# Isomorphism of Tor and tor functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

In [Theorem 6.32. pg 355 of Rotman's Hom. Alg.](http://www.math.unam.mx/javier/homologica/rotman.pdf), he proves that two different construction of Torsions conincide,

> $$Tor_n^R(A,B) \cong tor_n^R(A,B)$$

where

> If $B$ is a left $R$-module and $T = - \otimes_R B$, define left derived functor  $$Tor_n^R(-, B) = L_nT.$$
>
> If $A$ is a right $R$-module and $T=A \otimes_R - $, define
> $$tor_n^R(A,-) = L_nT.$$

It is a diagrammatic  proof so I hope you may have a look at link. There is one part of proof which I cannot understand:

> $W=Tor_1(K_{i-1},V_{j-1}), X=Tor_1(K_{i-1},V_{j}), \ldots $

This isn't clear from the definition given. What we should have is that
$$Tor_1(K_{i-1},V_j) \cong \ker d_1/im \,  d_2$$

where with $T=- \otimes_RV_j$, $$ TP_{i+2} \xrightarrow{d_2} TP_{i+1} \xrightarrow{d_1} TP_i \xrightarrow {d_0} K_{i-1} $$
why do the equalities hold? In fact even if it holds, shouldnt it be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you have a short exact sequence
$0\to K\to P \to L\to 0$ with $P$ projective and $M$ is a module (to the correct side) then the long exact sequence reads ($P$ projective!)

$$\operatorname{Tor}_1(P,M)=0\to \operatorname{Tor}_1(L,M)\to K\otimes M\to P\otimes M\to L\otimes M\to 0$$

so that $\operatorname{Tor}_1(L,M)$ is the kernel of $K\otimes M\to P\otimes M$. This is what Rotman is using throughout.